# Complex roots of $z^3 + \bar{z} = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots

I'm trying to find the complex roots of $z^3 + \bar{z} = 0$ using De Moivre.

Some suggested multiplying both sides by z first, but that seems wrong to me as it would add a root ( and I wouldn't know which root was the extra ).

I noticed that $z=a+bi$ and there exists $\theta$ such that the trigonometric representation of $z$ is $\left ( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right )\left ( \cos \theta + i \sin \theta \right )$ .

It seems that $-\bar{z} = -\left ( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right )\left ( \cos (-\theta) + i \sin (-\theta) \right )$

However, my trig is pretty rusty and I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: It doesn't add a root to multiply by $z$ since $z=0$ is already a root.

Comment: Why is $z=0$ already a root?

Comment: Another option, a sort of brute-force technique, is to write $z=a+bi$ and then equate real parts and imaginary parts to get two third-degree equations in $a$ and $b$. This sounds scary, but since you already know that $0+0i$ is a root, you will easily be able to eliminate this solution from the third-degree equations to get two second-degree equations in $a$ and $b$ which you should be able to solve. Let me know if you would like to see this written up in more detail.

Comment: Another thing that might be helpful in such problems: if $z\in\Bbb C$ and $|z|=1$ then $\overline{z}=z^{-1}$.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes What is $0^3 + \bar 0$?

Comment: I'm not sure about what answer to accept.  Basically, because this was homework, I was looking for hints so I could write my own answer based on what I know from the material in my course, which I ended up doing.  All the useful hints I upvoted, and also the interesting alternative answers.  Should I accept my own answer, or the hint answer which was most useful pointing me in the correct direction?

Comment: Or do I pick the most interesting ( to me ) alternative answer?  I'm not sure what the protocol is here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm going to take a stab at this.

Given:  $z^3 + \bar{z} = 0$

Therefore $z^3 = -\bar{z}$ and $|z^3| = |-\bar{z}|$ .

We have that $|-\bar{z}|=|\bar{z}|=|z|$ therefore $|z^3|=|z|$ and $|z||z||z|=|z|$.

Therefore $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1$.

Case 1: Assume $|z|=0$ then if

$z=a+bi\leftrightarrow|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=0\leftrightarrow a=0 \wedge b=0\leftrightarrow a+bi=0$

thus $z = 0$.

Case 2: Assume $|z|=1$

Let's multiply by $z$ and we get $z^4 = -z\bar{z}$.  We see that $z\bar{z} = |z|^2$ so we get $z^4 = -( |z|^2 )$ so from the above either:

therefore $z^4 = -|z| = -1$

The trigonometric representation of $-1$ is $1*( \cos \pi + i \sin \pi )$ so according to De Moivre:

$z^4 = r^4(\cos 4\theta + i \sin 4\theta ) = 1*( \cos \pi + i \sin \pi )$

These are two complex numbers in trigonometric form so:

$r^4 = 1$ and $4\theta = \pi + 2\pi*k$ or

$r=1$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi + 2\pi*k}{4}$ and each solution has the form:

$z_k = \cos( \frac{\pi + 2\pi*k}{4} ) + i \sin (\frac{\pi + 2\pi*k}{4})$

for $0\leq k \leq 3$.

Which together with Case 1 gives the following values for $z$:

$0,\pm\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}},\pm\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Can someone check my answer?  Thanks!

Comment: This is correct. And as Zarrax noted, there are 4 possibilities for $z_k$

Comment: $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ does not have absolute value 1, and so cannot be a solution, as you proved.

Comment: I must have screwed something up typing it into wolfram.  I typed:  solve \cos ( ( \pi+0*2*\pi )\4 ) + i*\sin ( \pi+0*2*\pi )\4 ) into wolphramalpha and it gave me $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 8):

Hint: First try to narrow down the value of $|z|$

Answer (score 6):

As has been observed by Thomas Andrews, $z=0$ is a root, so we will not be introducing extraneous roots if we multiply by $z$, or by $\overline{z}$.

From the answer by Aryabhata, you should be able to conclude that if $z\ne 0$, then $z$ has norm $1$.

Now it may be simplest to multiply by $\overline{z}$. We get the pleasantly symmetrical equation $z^2+\overline{z}\overline{z}=0$.  If $z$ has norm $1$, let $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. Then use De Moivre's Theorem.

Comment: What does $z$ has norm 1 mean?

Comment: The norm of $z=a+ib$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Equivalently, it is $\sqrt{z\overline{z}}$.

Comment: Ahh, I'm used to calling it absolute value, $|z|$. If I multiply by $\bar{z}$ I get $z^4 = -|z|^2$.  How do I conclude from that, that $|z|=1$?

Comment: Norms preserve multiplication. That is, if $c=ab$ then $|c| = |a|\cdot|b|$. Let's refer to the norm of $z$ as $n$, for "norm". You have $z^3 = -\bar z$, so $|z^3| = |-\bar z|$.  The right-hand side goes like this:  $|-\bar z| = |z| = n$.  (That's an exercise for you.)  And $|z^3| = {|z|}^3 = n^3$.  Since $z^3 = -\bar z$, their norms must be equal and we have $n^3 = n$.  The norm $n$ is always a non-negative real number, so $n=0$ or $n=1$ are the only possibilities.

Comment: The norm of a product is the product of the norms. So from $z^3=-\overline{z}$ you conclude that $|z|^3=|-\overline{z}|=|z|$. Therefore $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1$. In case $|z|=1$, multiply by $\overline{z}$. We get $z^2|z|^2+\overline{z}\overline{z}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $z = re^{i\theta}$. Then you are trying to solve $r^3e^{3i\theta} + re^{-i\theta} = 0$, which is the same as
$$r^3e^{3i\theta} = -re^{-i\theta}$$
Note that $-1 = e^{i\pi}$, so the above is equivalent to
$$r^3e^{3i\theta} = re^{i(\pi - \theta)}$$
Comparing magnitudes, you have $r^3 = r$, which is solved by $r = 0$ and $1$, and comparing arguments you must have $3\theta = \pi - \theta + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$ (when $r \neq 0$). Thus for some integer $k$ you have
$$\theta = {\pi \over 4} + k{\pi \over 2}$$
There are four values of $\theta$ in $[0,2\pi)$ that satisfy this, namely ${\pi \over 4}, {3\pi \over 4}, {5\pi \over 4}$, and ${7\pi \over 4}$. Thus the complex numbers satisfying your original equation are $0, e^{i {\pi \over 4}}, e^{i {3\pi \over 4}}, e^{i {5\pi \over 4}}$, and $e^{i {7\pi \over 4}}$. In rectangular coordinates these are $0$ and $\pm {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \pm {i \over \sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I got 0 and $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ as the answers.  Maybe you could check against my solution and see what's correct?

Comment: Your solution is right until right before the end... you left out the imaginary parts of the solutions, $\sin({\pi \over 4}) = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$ etc.

Comment: I miss typed into wolfram - () weren't balanced.

Comment: I'm still getting strange stuff in wolfram: $\pm\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}},\pm\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: How does an equation of order 3 come out with 5 solutions?

Comment: The wolfram solutions mean what I wrote. Just take sine and cosine of the various arguments and you'll see the answer. It can have 5 solutions... only polynomials of degree 3 will have to have at most 3 solutions and this isn't a polynomial.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: How do you know to look for 4 solutions in $[0,2\pi)$?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** *in view of the comments bellow by JimConant and PeterTaylor. If there is still any error the fault is mine.*

This is an alternative solution to the trigonometric one. We will use the algebraic method. Let $z=x+iy$. We have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &=&z^{3}+\overline{z} \\
0 &=&\left( x+iy\right) ^{3}+\left( x-iy\right)  \\
&=&x^{3}+x-3xy^{2}+i\left( 3x^{2}y-y^{3}-y\right)  \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0=x(x^{2}+1-3y^{2}) \\ 
0=y(y^{2}+1-3x^{2}).
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{1}$$

One of the roots is $$x_{1}=y_{1}=0.\tag{1a}$$ The remaining *real* roots satisfy the system

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0=x^{2}+1-3y^{2} \\ 
0=y^{2}+1-3x^{2}
\end{array}
\right.  &\Leftrightarrow &\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0=x^{2}+1-3y^{2} \\ 
0=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}x^{2}+1-3x^{2}
\end{array}
\right.  \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0=x^{2}+1-3y^{2} \\ 
0=4-8x^{2}
\end{array}
\right.  \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0=1-2y^{2} \\ 
0=1-2x^{2}.
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{eqnarray*}
\tag{2}$$

The last system means that $$y=\pm x\tag{3}$$ and that

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=&\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}, \\
y &=&\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{3a}$$

Combining the above results, we conclude that the following five complex numbers

$$
z_{1} =0,\tag{4}$$
$$
z_{2} =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}+i\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},\quad z_{3} =-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}-i\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},
\tag{5}$$
$$z_{4} =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}-i\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},\quad z_{5} =-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}+i\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},
\tag{6}$$

are the solutions of the given equation $$z^{3}+\overline{z}=0.\tag{7}$$

Comment: Is it really true that having equations symmetric with respect to $x$ and $y$ implies $x=y$? It seems to me this only implies that if $(x,y)$ is a solution then so is $(y,x)$.

Comment: @JimConant: You are right! I was wrong.

Comment: @JimConant Thanks for finding the error. I will try to reformulate the solution.

Comment: @JimConant I edited the answer. I hope now the solution is correctly justified.

Comment: You only find 3 solutions, but you haven't explained why you're discarding two (x, y) pairs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I added the two solutions corresponding to $y=-x$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @JimConant Thanks for the verification!

Answer (score 2):

That is a comment to the comment "should there be only 3 roots?"  in Zarrax answer.  Actually, the questions is "why isn´t there 9 roots?".  This is the right question to ask since the intersection of the two curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$
$$ x^3-3xy^2 +x = 0$$
$$ 3x^2y-y^3 -y = 0$$
is your solution set (just expand out $z^3+\bar{z}$).  Now, the intersection of two degree 3 equations should have $3x3= 9$ solutions (by Bezout´s theorem). The 4 roots we are missing at "infinity" or in the $\mathbb{C}^2$ plane. We could apply the same thing to the function $z^2+z$.  As complex polynomial, we should expect 2 roots.  As the real system $(x,y) \rightarrow (x^2-y^2+x,2xy+y)$ we expect four real roots.

Comment: According to my computations the 4 "missing" roots are in the $\mathbb{C}^2$ plane: $(0,i),(0,-i),(i,0),(0,i)$.

Comment: Correction: $(0,i),(0,−i),(i,0),(-i,0)$.