# Find the $z\in \Bbb C$ such that $\bar z=z^3$

Tags: complex-numbers

Here is what I've done.  Let $z\in \Bbb C$ be of the form $a+ib$, lets assume in this case that $a,b\not=0$. We have that $\bar z=a-ib$, and $z^3=a^3-3ab^2+i(3a^2b-b^3)$, so to find the correct $z$, it has to satisfy: 
$$\begin{cases}
a= a^3-3ab^2\\
-b= 3a^2b-b^3\\
\end{cases}$$
wich is the same as: 
$$\begin{cases}
a=a( a^2-3b^2)\\
-b=b (3a^2-b^2)\\
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
1=a^2-3b^2\\
1=b^2 -3a^2\\
\end{cases}$$
then, $a^2-3b^2=b^2 -3a^2 \Rightarrow 4a^2=4b^2 \Rightarrow a^2=b^2 \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
a=b \;\text{ or,}\\
a=-b\\
\end{cases}$

I thought this was correct, and to try it out I went to Wolfram, and it turns out that the examples that came to my mind didn't satisfied this. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What about the cases $a=0$ or $b=0$ ? For $b=0$ we have $a=1,-1$, for example.

Comment: Just because two equations are equal to a number (here 1) does not mean that the two equations can be set equal?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was considering the case when both numbers are $\not=0$

Comment: Take a look at [Complex roots of $z^3 + \bar{z} = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145102)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use radial coordinates. If $z \neq 0$, then your equation is equivalent to $|z|^2 = z^4$.

For $r$, we have $r^2 = r^4$, which amounts to $r^2 - 1 = (r - 1)(r + 1) = 0$. Since $r > 0$ by hypothesis, we have $r = 1$.

Pick out polar and radial parts: if $z = r e^{i \theta}$, then we must have that $4 \theta$ is a multiple of $2 \pi$, hence $\theta = 0, \pi/2, \pi, 3 \pi/2$.

The amusing thing is that in assuming $a,b$ both nonzero, you excluded all the possible solutions, which are $1, i, -1, -i$, and $0$.

Comment: Oops, forgot the solution $z = 0$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $|\bar{z}|=|z|$. Thus, $|z|=|\bar{z}|=|z|^3\implies|z|\in\{0,1\}$.

If $|z|=0$, then $z=0$.

If $|z|=1$, then $\bar{z}=1/z$. Thus, $1/z=\bar{z}=z^3\implies z^4=1$. Thus, $z\in\{1,-1,i,-i\}$.

Just to be clear, there are $5$ solutions: $z\in\{0,1,-1,i,-i\}$

---

To answer [Ana's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682620/find-the-z-in-bbb-c-such-that-bar-z-z3/682639#comment1432672_682628): this generalizes to $\bar{z}=z^n$. $|z|=|\bar{z}|=|z|^n\implies|z|\in\{0,1\}$.

If $|z|=0$, then $z=0$.

If $|z|=1$, then $\bar{z}=1/z$. Thus, $1/z=\bar{z}=z^n\implies z^{n+1}=1$. That is,
$$
z\in\{0\}\cup\{e^{i2k\pi/(n+1)}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ and }0\le k\le n\}
$$
These are precisely the solutions to $z^{n+2}-z=0$.

Comment: So $0$ is indeed an solution, isn't it?

Comment: @imranfat: it is indeed! I have stated that explicitly to be clearer.

Comment: Yes, yes, I see it :)

Answer (score 2):

Ana, take a look at this:

Say we have $a+b=1$ and $a-b=1$ It follows very easily that $a=1$ AND $b=0$. However, with your approach, we could say $a+b=a-b$ and here we have infinite options for $a$

Comment: oh silly me... thanks

Comment: So indeed in the original question if you substitute $a^2=b^2$ in $1=a^2-3b^2$, you see that there is no solution. This means that there is no solution with $a\ne0$, $b\ne0$, which is true.